# How to handle processing of large file on GAE?

Tags: python, algorithm, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm looking for a powerful and fast way to handle processing of large file in Google App Engine.

It works as the following (simplified workflow at the end):

1. The customer send a CSV file, that our server will treat, line by line.
2. Once the file is uploaded, an entry is added in the NDB datastore `Uploads` with the CSV name, file path (to Google Storage) and some basic informations. Then, a Task is created, called "pre-processing".
3. The pre-processing task will loop over all the lines of the CSV file (could be millions) and will add a NDB entry to `UploadEntries` model, for each line, with the CSV id, the line, the data to extract/treat, and some indicators (boolean) on if this line has started processing, and ended processing ("is_treating", "is_done")
4. Once the pre-processing task has ended, it updates the information to the client "XXX lines will be processed"
5. A call to `Uploads.next()` is made. The `next` method will :

   - Search the `UploadEntries` that has `is_treating` and `is_done` at false,
   - Will add a task in a Redis datastore for the next line found. (The Redis datastore is used because the work here is made on servers not managed by Google)
   - Will also create a new entry in the task `Process-healthcheck` (This task is runned after 5 minutes and checks that 7) has been correctly executed. If not, it considers that the Redis/Outside server has failed and do the same as 7), without the result ("error" instead)).
   - Then, it updates `UploadEntries.is_treating` to True for that entry.
6. The outside server will process the data, and returns the results by making a POST request to an endpoint on the server.
7. That endpoint update the `UploadEntries` entry in the datastore (including "`is_treating`" and "`is_done`"), and call `Uploads.next()` to start the next line.
8. In Uploads.next, when searching for the next entries returns nothing, I consider the file to be finally treated, and call the task `post-process` that will rebuild the CSV with the treated data, and returns it to the customer.

---

Here's a few things to keep in mind :

1. The servers that does the real work are outside of Google AppEngine, that's why I had to come up with Redis.
2. The current way of doing things give me a flexibility on the number of parallel entries to process : In the 5), the `Uploads.next()` methods contains a `limit` argument that let me search for `n` process in parallel. Can be 1, 5, 20, 50.
3. I can't just add all the lines from the `pre-processing` task directly to Redis becase in that case, the next customer will have to wait for the first file to be finished processing, and this will pile-up to take too long

---

But this system has various issues, and that's why I'm turning to your help :

1. Sometimes, this system is so fast that the Datastore is not yet updated correctly and when calling `Uploads.next()`, the entries returned are already being processed (it's just that `entry.is_treating = True` is not yet pushed to the database)
2. The Redis or my server (I don't really know) sometime loose the task, or the POST request after the processing is not made, so the task never goes to `is_done = True`. That's why I had to implement a Healcheck system, to ensure the line is correctly treated no matter what. This has a double advantage : The name of that task contains the csv ID, and the line. Making it unique per file. If I the datastore is not up to date and the same task is run twice, the creation of the healthcheck will fail because the same name already exist, letting me know that there is a concurrence issue, so I ignore that task because it means the Datastore is not yet up to date.

---

I initiall thought about running the file in one independant process, line by line, but this has the big disadvantage of not being able to run multiple line in parallel. Moreover, Google limits the running of a task to 24h for dedicated targets (not default), and when the file is really big, it can run for longer than 24h.

For information, if it helps, I'm using **Python**

---

And to simplify the workflow, here's what I'm trying to achieve in the best way possible :

- Process a large file, run multiple paralllel process, one per line.
- Send the work to an outside server using Redis. Once done, that outside server returns the result via a POST request to the main server
- The main server then update the information about that line, and goes to the next line

I'd really appreciate if someone had a better way of doing this. I really believe I'm not the first to do that kind of work and I'm pretty sure I'm not doing it correctly.

(I believe Stackoverflow is the best section of Stack Exchange to post that kind of question since it's an algorithm question, but it's also possible I didn't saw a better network for that. If so, I'm sorry about that).

Comment: I think you could use app engine mapreduce for this, it can read CSV from GCS line by line with buffers, running it on multiple instances. It will process N lines per request, depending on your settings. But, GAE instances are expensive.

Answer (score 1):

> The servers that does the real work are outside of Google AppEngine

Have you considered using [Google Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) for processing large files instead?
It is a managed service that will handle the file splitting and processing for you.

Based on initial thoughts here is an outline process:

- User uploads files direct to google cloud storage, using [signed urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-resumable) or blobstore API
- A request from AppEngine launches a small compute engine instance that initiates a blocking request (`BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner`) to launch the dataflow task. (I'm afraid it needs to be a compute instance because of sandbox and blocking I/O issues).
- When the dataflow task is finished the compute engine instance is unblocked and posts a message into pubsub.
- The pubsub message invokes a webhook on the AppEngine service that changes the tasks state from 'in progress' to 'complete' so the user can fetch their results.

Comment: Awesome, Dataflow seems right for me. Do you know if it works with inputs being XLS/XLSX, it with what I start (so I can't only read lines by lines)?

Comment: You will probably have to make a custom source. There are [convenience classes](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io-python#convenience-source-base-classes) for developing custom file readers. Perhaps this could be combined with [one of many python libraries for reading XLS](http://www.python-excel.org/).

Comment: Ok that's what I was suspecting. I started to read an graps the idea behind Dataflow, but there is still one question bothering me : How can I apply a `Transform` method (home made I believe) that needs to wait on the outside server to reply? Do I block the current process and query the state of the response every n seconds, or is there a better way?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of having Dataflow do the work that the 'outside' server is doing in your example. (Forgive me this might be radical change!) Either you get AppEngine to launch Dataflow (Batch mode) via Compute Engine when files in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) are available to process. Or your run Dataflow all the time (Streaming mode) and it processes file upload events (perhaps directly from GCS). The choice depends on how active you expect your pipeline to be. I assumed the pipeline would not be active all the time so I went with batch in my initial answer.

Comment: @CyrilN. I think maybe I understand your problem a bit better in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41029264/1900169

Comment: Yes, I believe too :) I commented on the other question then :)